# Guava: Why is there no Lists.filter() function?

Tags: java, list, filter, guava

Is there a reason there's

```
Lists.transform()
```

but no

```
Lists.filter()
```

?

How do I filter a list correctly? I could use

```
new ArrayList(Collection2.filter())
```

of course, but this way it's not guaranteed that my ordering stays the same, if I understand correctly.

Comment: FYI, List.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(...)) is generally faster than new ArrayList(Collection2.filter(...)). The ArrayList constructor calls size() on the filtered collection, and computing the size requires that the filter be applied to every element of the original list.

Comment: @JaredLevy Maybe instead of `List.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(...))`, it should say `Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(...)) `.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It wasn't implemented because it would expose a perilous large number of slow methods, such as #get(index) on the returned List view (inviting performance bugs). And ListIterator would be a pain to implement as well (though I submitted a [patch](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=110) years ago to cover that).

Since indexed methods can't be efficient in the filtered List view, it's better to just go with a filtered Iterable, which doesn't have them.

Comment: You are assuming that a list view would be returned. However #filter could be implemented as returning a new materialised list, which is actually what I would expect from a filter method for lists as opposed to the one on Iterable.

Comment: @FelixLeipold This would muddy the waters however. As it is, `filter` consistently means a view (along with the behaviour that implies) whether that's `Iterables.filter`, `Sets.filter` etc.  Since `Iterables.filter` combines easily with `copyOf` on any `ImmutableCollection`, I find this a good design trade-off (vs coming up with extra methods & names, like `filteredCopy` or whatnot, for combinations of simple utilities).

Answer (score 37):

You can use `Iterables.filter`, which will definitely maintain ordering.

Note that by constructing a new list, you'll be *copying* the elements (just references, of course) - so it won't be a live view onto the original list. Creating a view would be pretty tricky - consider this situation:

```
Predicate<StringBuilder> predicate = 
    /* predicate returning whether the builder is empty */
List<StringBuilder> builders = Lists.newArrayList();
List<StringBuilder> view = Lists.filter(builders, predicate);

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    builders.add(new StringBuilder());
}
builders.get(8000).append("bar");

StringBuilder firstNonEmpty = view.get(0);
```

That would have to iterate over the whole original list, applying the filter to everything. I suppose it could require that the predicate matching didn't change over the lifetime of the view, but that would be not-entirely-satisfactory.

(This is just guessing, mind you. Maybe one of the Guava maintainers will chip in with the *real* reason :)

Comment: `Collections2.filter.iterator` just calls `Iterables.filter`, so the result is the same.

Comment: @skaffman: In which case I'd use the `Iterables.filter` version just for clarity.

Comment: ...unless you need a `view.size()` somewhere later in code :)

Answer (score 28):

> I could use `new List(Collection2.filter())` of course, but this way it's not guaranteed that my ordering stays the same.

This isn't true.  `Collections2.filter()` is a lazily-evaluated function - it doesn't actually filter your collection until you start accessing the filtered version. For example, if you iterate over the filtered version, then the filtered elements will pop out of the iterator in the same order as your original collection (minus the ones filtered out, obviously).

Perhaps you were thinking that it does the filtering up front, then dumps the results into an arbitrary, unordered Collection of some form - it doesn't.

So if you use the output of `Collections2.filter()` as the input to a new list, then your original order *will* be retained.

Using static imports (and the `Lists.newArrayList` function), it becomes fairly succinct:

```
List filteredList = newArrayList(filter(originalList, predicate));
```

Note that while `Collections2.filter` will not eagerly iterate over the underlying collection, `Lists.newArrayList` *will* - it will extract all elements of the filtered collection and copy them into a new `ArrayList`.

Comment: It's more like: `List filteredList = newArrayList(filter(originalList, new Predicate<T>() { @Override public boolean apply(T input) { return (...); } }));` or ie. `List filteredList = newArrayList(filter(originalList, Predicates.notNull()));`

Comment: @Xaerxess: Oops, yes, forgot the predicate... fixed

Comment: @Bozho: Thanks... took me long enough :)

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned by Jon, you can use `Iterables.filter(..)` or `Collections2.filter(..)`; and if you don't need a live view, you can use `ImmutableList.copyOf(Iterables.filter(..))` or `Lists.newArrayList( Iterables.filter(..))` and, yes, ordering will be maintained.

If you are really interested in the *why* part, you can visit https://github.com/google/guava/issues/505 for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Summing up what the others said, you can easily create a generic wrapper to filter lists:

```
public static <T> List<T> filter(Iterable<T> userLists, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.filter(userLists, predicate));
}
```